# Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is not allowed - EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I need to update few properties in the DB table, so while trying to update them I am getting the error:

> Adding a relationship with an entity which is in the Deleted state is
> not allowed** on SaveChanges() method execution.

In the `SaveChanges()` method, it failing at the first line only which is `ChangeTracker.Entries()`

```cs
var changedTableTypes = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.State != EntityState.Unchanged)
    .Select(e => e.Entity.GetObjectTypeExcludingEFProxy())
    .Distinct();
```

Here is the block of code where I am calling that `SaveChanges()` method.

```cs
public static Quote CreateAmendment(DbContext db, long quoteId)
{
    var originalQuote = db.Quote.Single(x => x.ID == quoteId);
    if (originalQuote.Original_Quote == null)
    {
        var amendedOriginalQuoteNumber = GenerateAmendmentQuoteNumber(originalQuote, false);
        originalQuote.MarkAsAmended(amendedOriginalQuoteNumber);
    }

    var sourceQuote = originalQuote.Original_Quote ?? originalQuote;
    var clonedQuote = QuoteCreation.CreateAmendmentFrom(db, originalQuote);
    clonedQuote.Quote_Number = GenerateAmendmentQuoteNumber(originalQuote, true);
    clonedQuote.Amendment_Number = (sourceQuote.Quote_Amendments.Max(x => x.Amendment_Number) ?? 1) + 1;

    sourceQuote.Quote_Amendments.Add(clonedQuote);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return clonedQuote;
}
```

In the above method or any other calling methods, I am not deleting anything, I am just trying to change those properties details and create a copy of the Quote as a new row in the DB table.

It failing while adidng `Quote_Amendments` which is

```cs
public virtual ICollection<Quote> Quote_Amendments { get; set; } = new HashSet<Quote>();
```

Config file:

```cs
HasMany(x => x.Quote_Amendments)
    .WithOptional(x => x.Original_Quote)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.Original_Quote_ID);
```

Please, someone help me with this. I've been spending lot of time on this. Thanks in advance.

Tried to update a DB table and expected it to updated but I am getting the error as mentioned in the description.

**Update-1:**
When I was debugging I tested by skipping few blocks of code each time in `CreateAmendmentForm()`. I found the lines of code which causing the error again it just adding child model only. This may help to help me.

```
foreach (var module in property.Quote_Property_Module)
{
    var clonedModuleAssignment = new Quote_Property_Module
    {
      Module_ID = module.Module_ID,
      Frequency_ID = module.Frequency_ID,
      IsLocked = module.IsLocked,
      AnnualNumberOfVisits = module.AnnualVisits,
      AuditSchedules = module.AuditSchedules.ToList(),
    };
                
    clonedProperty.Quote_Property_Module.Add(clonedModuleAssignment);
}
```

**Update-2:**
[image]

Comment: "I am not deleting anything" Maybe, but since almost all essential code is invisible we can't tell if there's any code that may give rise to covert deletions.

Comment: The other code just creates some amendment number and checks whether its renewal or upgrade type and then just builds the model. Other than that its not doing anything.

Comment: Well, in `CreateAmendment` there are only two lines of code that do something with EF. The first line doesn't delete anything. The rest is a secret. Impossible to answer.

Comment: Please see the above update, thanks.

Comment: At least it's a bit closer to the culprit. Still not an obvious cause though. Try to see which entries in `ChangeTracker.Entries()` have the `Deleted` state at various stages in the process.

Comment: I tried adding `ChangeTracker.Entries()` just before `SaveChanges()` but it throwing me an error. Please see above screenshot.

Comment: Then you should do this in an earlier stage. It may also indicate that the context's lifecycle is too long. When do you initialize the context?

Comment: Its coming to controller like DependencyInjection pattern and from the controller endpoint to service class. From service class to another static class to build the model.

Comment: Please @GertArnold could you help me, I'm still stuck here.